# Rows common on certain columns, different on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

How would I get the rows which are the same on some columns for 2 dataframes, but different on a given column?

eg,

Pick the rows which have the same values in the 2 dfs for cols [A,B,C], but have different value for column 'actual'

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(range(10)),
                   "B":list(range(10,20)),
                   "C":list(range(20,30)),
                   "D":list(range(30,40)),
                   "actual":[1 for x in range(10)]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(range(15)),
                   "B":list(range(5,20)),
                   "C":list(range(15,30)),
                   "D":list(range(45,60)),
                   "actual":[0 for x in range(15)]})

    df.iloc[5] = [5,10,20,20,1]
Out[12]: 
   A   B   C   D  actual
0  0  10  20  30       1
1  1  11  21  31       1
2  2  12  22  32       1
3  3  13  23  33       1
4  4  14  24  34       1
5  5  10  20  20       1
6  6  16  26  36       1
7  7  17  27  37       1
8  8  18  28  38       1
9  9  19  29  39       1

df2
Out[13]: 
     A   B   C   D  actual
0    0   5  15  45       0
1    1   6  16  46       0
2    2   7  17  47       0
3    3   8  18  48       0
4    4   9  19  49       0
5    5  10  20  50       0
6    6  11  21  51       0
7    7  12  22  52       0
8    8  13  23  53       0
9    9  14  24  54       0
10  10  15  25  55       0
11  11  16  26  56       0
12  12  17  27  57       0
13  13  18  28  58       0
14  14  19  29  59       0
```

I want all the indexes in df2 which are the same in df1, but have different 'actual' values. For example

```
A  B   C   D
5  10  20  50
```

which is index 5 in df2.

Could anyone help? :)

Comment: `A: 5, B: 10, C: 20, D: 50` doesn't appear in the first df?

Comment: @ayhan My bad, fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.merge(df2, on=list('ABCD'))
```

gives you a DataFrame where both DataFrames have the same values on those for columns. For the `actual` column it will generate two columns: `actual_x` and `actual_y`.

```
   A   B   C   D  actual_x  actual_y
0  5  10  20  50         1         0
```

If you want to pass another condition, this can be done with:

```
df.merge(df2, on=list('ABCD'))[lambda v: v['actual_x'] != v['actual_y']]
# Or
df.merge(df2, on=list('ABCD')).query('actual_x != actual_y')
```

This will give you a DataFrame where both df's have the same values on `ABCD`  but have different values on the `actual`  column.

Comment: I am not sure if you want to include column `D`  in merge but if not, you can just drop it. Then it will generate `D_x` and `D_y`. If you want the one on the second DataFrame, then you can just index it with `[D_y]`.

Comment: This crashes on large dataframes, Is there a way just getting the indices of the rows? eg, [1,4] if the common row is index 1 in df1 and 4 in df2 @ayhan

Comment: After the merge, yes. But if you want to do that without the merge you can check each individual column by yourself but I am not sure if this will help. Does it crash because of memory? How large are the DataFrames?

Comment: Over 2m rows, its okay I just needed one row to prove an example. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hey @ayhan, apologies I was mistaken, I need all the rows now. However, it keeps crashing, likely because of memory. My two dataframes have 120k rows and 1.7k rows respectively. After merging they have over 14m rows!

Comment: I think the reason is because I have duplicated rows. How can i keep a final dataframe where the same row only appears twice, both with different values in 'actual'?

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicate rows? Do you want to drop them?